# Set excel print areas based on row heights

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have been battling with this code for several days now and would appreciate some guidance on where I am going wrong.

My project is to create a printable document format containing manufacturing instructions and spaces for operators to write manual entries, which requires a minimum cell size when printed onto A4. These instructions will be varied but in all cases will be signed in column B, and in some cases will be countersigned. The marker in column B for a signature is "Op" and the marker for a countersignature is "Check".

In order to regulate cell size for the printed document I am attempting to count row heights up until a fixed total (832), from that point I want the code to go up and look for the first "Op", if the "Op" has a "Check" in the cell below then insert a page break below "Check", if not then insert a page break below "Op". From there I want the code to continue to the bottom of the document inserting page breaks every time it counts 832 total rows.

I am not sure if that methodology is the best for achieving what I am aiming for but would appreciate some feedback on what I have so far, I am getting an run time error 1004 on this code and it is inserting page breaks in the wrong places.

```
Sub TotalHeight()
    Dim HowTall As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim TotalHeight As Long

    HowTall = 0
    Count = 0
    TotalHeight = 0


Dim cell As Range
       For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        'If Not cell.Hidden Then
            HowTall = HowTall + cell.RowHeight
            'Count = Count + 1
            If HowTall > 832 Then
                Debug.Print cell.Row
                For tmpcounter = 0 To 100
                   ' If (Range(cell.Row).Offset(-tmpcounter, 0).Value) = "Op" Then
                    If cell.Offset(-tmpcounter, 0).Value = "Op" Then
                        If cell.Offset(-tmpcounter + 1, 0).Value = "Check" Then
                            'Found Check - get current row
                            PageBreakRowNo = cell.Offset(-tmpcounter + 1, 0).Row
                            Debug.Print "Check found at row " & PageBreakRowNo
                            Sheets("Dispensary").HPageBreaks.Add Before:=cell.Offset(-tmpcounter + 2, 0)
                        Else
                            'Only found Op - Get current row
                            PageBreakRowNo = cell.Offset(-tmpcounter, 0).Row
                            Debug.Print "Op found at row " & PageBreakRowNo
                            Sheets("Dispensary").HPageBreaks.Add Before:=cell.Offset(-tmpcounter + 1, 0)
                        End If
                    End If
                 Next tmpcounter
            End If ' end of of HowTall >832 loop
         Next 'end of for each cell in Column B loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what rows you get the errors, and where pagebreaks are inserted where they shouldn't be. Could you show us a printscreen of your sheet where you indicate the pagebreaks and where they should be?

Comment: Also does your sheet contain more then 2 pages, if so reset your `HowTall` to 0 after inserting the pagebreak, otherwise it keeps inserting them every row.

Comment: Also if Check only exists after Op, then the code could be simplified by using  `If cell.Offset(-tmpcounter, 0).value = "Op" OR cell.Offset(-tmpcounter, 0).value = "Check" Then` and place here the code to insert a pagebreak. This way you can remove the other `If` statement.

Comment: this is what it looks like currently, it is inserting page breaks after every Op and every Check. Check does only exist after Op so that would be good to eliminate one of the If statements!

Comment: Also you forget to stop going upward after you found the check.

Comment: ![Image](https://ibb.co/ixzYTQ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added my suggested improvements in your original code:

```
Sub TotalHeight()
Dim HowTall As Long
Dim Count As Long
Dim TotalHeight As Long
Dim tmpcounter1 As Long

HowTall = 0
Count = 0
TotalHeight = 0


Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'If Not cell.Hidden Then
        HowTall = HowTall + cell.RowHeight
        'Count = Count + 1
        If HowTall > 832 Then
            Debug.Print cell.Row
            For tmpcounter = 0 To 100
                If cell.Offset(-tmpcounter, 0).Value = "Op" Or cell.Offset(-tmpcounter, 0).Value = "Check" Then
                        PageBreakRowNo = cell.Offset(-tmpcounter + 1, 0).Row
                        tmpcounter1 = tmpcounter
                        Debug.Print "Op / Check found at row " & PageBreakRowNo
                        Sheets("Dispensary").HPageBreaks.Add Before:=cell.Offset(-tmpcounter + 2, 0)
                        Exit for 'to stop looking upwards
                End If
             Next tmpcounter
        HowTall = 0 'reset HowTall to start again for the next page
            For i = tmpcounter1 +1 to 0 Step -1 'Calculate the HowTall lost due to stepping back
                HowTall = HowTall + cell.Offset(i,0).RowHeight
            Next i
        End If ' end of of HowTall >832 loop
     Next 'end of for each cell in Column B loop

End Sub
```